# Memcache PHP Extension on Windows

Tags: php, iis, memcached

I have found plenty of tutorials covering how to install memcache in Windows and install the PHP extension. My situation though is slightly unusual:

I'm using iis, not apache.
I don't need to install memcache on the server (it has its own dedicated server already setup). I ONLY need to install the extension.

I thought I simply needed to add the PHP_memcache.dll extension to the PHP extension folder and add it to PHP.ini

This causes an error loading the PHP module (unable to load dynamic library).

Is this error likely to be caused because memcache isn't installed on the server and what can I do to solve it?

Comment: This is a job for ... http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Thanks, that software really helped. I found that I was using the thread safe version by mistake.

Comment: Good to know, I'll add it as answer then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors while loading extensions in Windows are not as helpful as they are in Linux, so you need a tool like dependency walker to fish out the problem.

http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score -1):

If you are using XAMPP on Windows you probably have installed the 32bit-XAMPP version.
So make sure you are using the 32bit (x86) DLL of Memcache.

The DLL download List for windows can be found here: http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache/3.0.8/windows